# For loop to iterate through all values and repeat input process if variable not found - C++

Tags: c++, loops

I'm still fairly new to programming and I'm a little confused as to how to get this to work. I want to loop through all Years in the Array and if it is not found, I want to print out an error message and prompt the user to try again. I've tried doing an else statement but it keeps repeating the error message until the year is found. Any suggestions?

```
void option2(Vector<WindLogType> &windlog)
{

    int month = 0;
    int year;
    const int SIZE = windlog.size();
    float *averagetemp = new float[SIZE];
    float *sd = new float[SIZE];
    float *sum = new float[SIZE];
    float *sigma = new float[SIZE];
    float *nrofel = new float[SIZE];
    int *check = new int[SIZE];
    int counter = 0;
    int yearCheck = 0;

        while(yearCheck==0){
            cout << "Please enter a year: " << endl;
            cin >> year;

            for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            {

                if(windlog[i].d.GetYear() == year)
                {

                    month = windlog[i].d.GetMonth();
                    counter = month;
                    nrofel[counter] = nrofel[counter] + 1;
                    sum[counter] += windlog[i].temp.GetTemperature();
                    averagetemp[counter] = (sum[counter]/nrofel[counter]);
                    sigma[counter] += (windlog[i].temp.GetTemperature() - averagetemp[counter])*(windlog[i].temp.GetTemperature() - averagetemp[counter]);
                    sd[counter] = sqrt((sigma[counter])/(nrofel[counter] - 1));
                    check[counter] = 1;

                }

            }
            for(int start = 1; start < 13; start++)
            {

            if(check[start] == 1)
            {
                cout << checkMonth(start) << ": " << averagetemp[start] << " degrees C, stdev: " << sd[start] << '\n';
            }
            else
            {
                cout << checkMonth(start) << ": No Data" << '\n';
            }


            }

            yearCheck = 1;

        }

        delete[] averagetemp;
        delete[] sum;
        delete[] sigma;
        delete[] sd;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the yearCheck flag and add continue statement

```
void option2(Vector<WindLogType> &windlog)
{

    int month = 0;
    int year;
    const int SIZE = windlog.size();
    float *averagetemp = new float[SIZE];
    float *sd = new float[SIZE];
    float *sum = new float[SIZE];
    float *sigma = new float[SIZE];
    float *nrofel = new float[SIZE];
    int *check = new int[SIZE];
    int counter = 0;
    int yearCheck = 0;

        while(yearCheck==0){
            cout << "Please enter a year: " << endl;
            cin >> year;

            for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            {

                if(windlog[i].d.GetYear() == year)
                {

                    month = windlog[i].d.GetMonth();
                    counter = month;
                    nrofel[counter] = nrofel[counter] + 1;
                    sum[counter] += windlog[i].temp.GetTemperature();
                    averagetemp[counter] = (sum[counter]/nrofel[counter]);
                    sigma[counter] += (windlog[i].temp.GetTemperature() - averagetemp[counter])*(windlog[i].temp.GetTemperature() - averagetemp[counter]);
                    sd[counter] = sqrt((sigma[counter])/(nrofel[counter] - 1));
                    check[counter] = 1;

///////////// CHANGE #1 /////////////////
yearCheck = 1;

                }

            }

///////////// CHANGE #2 /////////////////
if(!yearCheck )
continue;

            for(int start = 1; start < 13; start++)
            {

            if(check[start] == 1)
            {
                cout << checkMonth(start) << ": " << averagetemp[start] << " degrees C, stdev: " << sd[start] << '\n';
            }
            else
            {
                cout << checkMonth(start) << ": No Data" << '\n';
            }


            }

            yearCheck = 1;

        }

        delete[] averagetemp;
        delete[] sum;
        delete[] sigma;
        delete[] sd;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the arrays `averagetemp`, `check` etc. a length equal be `windlog.size()` however, you are later using them as if they have one element per month. It would be better to just give them a length of 12.

You use the arrays as if they start with a value of zero in each element but you never give them that value. You can put `{}` after your array declaration to start it with zero values.

```
void option2(Vector<WindLogType> &windlog)
{
    int year;
    static constexpr int monthsInYear = 12;
    const int SIZE = windlog.size();
    float averagetemp[monthsInYear];
    float sd[monthsInYear];

    while(true) {
        float sum[monthsInYear]{};
        float sigma[monthsInYear]{};
        float nrofel[monthsInYear]{};

        cout << "Please enter a year: " << endl;
        cin >> year;

        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            if(windlog[i].d.GetYear() == year)
            {
                month = windlog[i].d.GetMonth();
                counter = month - 1;
                nrofel[counter] += 1;
                const float temperature = windlog[i].temp.GetTemperature()
                sum[counter] += temperature;
                averagetemp[counter] = (sum[counter]/nrofel[counter]);
                //This won't give an accurate value for sigma as it uses the current estimate of the mean, instead of the mean of all the samples
                //there are lots of ways of fixing this but which one is the most accurate will depend on sample size.
                sigma[counter] += (temperature - averagetemp[counter])*(temperature - averagetemp[counter]);
            }
        }
        bool yearsDataIsValid = true;
        for(int start = 0; start < 12; start++)
        {
            if(nrofel[start] == 0)
            {
                //making `checkMonth` zero based instead of adding 1 might be a good idea
                cout << checkMonth(start + 1) << ": No Data" << '\n';
                yearsDataIsValid = false;
                break;
            }
            if((nrofel[counter] - 1) == 0)
            {
                //I don't know what the standard deviation of one value is
                //but division by zero is an error
                sd[start] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                sd[start] = sqrt((sigma[start]) / (nrofel[start] - 1))
            }
            cout << checkMonth(start + 1) << ": " << averagetemp[start] << " degrees C, stdev: " << sd[start] << '\n';
        }
        if(yearsDataIsValid)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```